# Why do I need to declare accumulator variables in the same block as the loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, accumulator

I've set up an accumulator algorithm, but I initialized the accumulator variable outside of the block of code (in this example: main() ) that contains the accumulator loop:

```
alphabet = ""

def main():
    # 97 - 122 are the ASCII codes for the lower case alphabet
    for i in range( 97, 123 ):
        alphabet += chr( i )
    print alphabet

main()
```

For some reason I get this:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'alphabet' referenced before assignment

**The Solution** I found was to initialize the variable inside the same block as the loop.

```
def main():
    alphabet = ""

    # 97 - 122 are the ASCII codes for the lower case alphabet
    for i in range( 97, 123 ):
        alphabet += chr( i )
    print alphabet

main()
```

**My Question** is *why* is this necessary?

Am I right in generalizing the problem and assuming that I need to initialize the variable in the same block as the loop, or is my problem specific to this example?

Is there some trait of python that I'm missing?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's definitely the problem. I should've searched the error message itself before posting the question. Sorry for the duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Think of this alphabet += chr( i ) as shorthand for alphabet = alphabet + chr( i ). You are attempting to add chr(i) to alphabet and the first time this executes alphabet does not exist yet.

Comment: I understand the += symbol. What I don't understand is why alphabet doesn't exist yet. I thought I'd already initialized it. Oh wait, do I need to make it public?